# How many concurrent read call can Redis server handle?

Tags: linux, redis

I am planning to build a poll server for simple lists in Redis. Hundred and thousands of devices will poll every second to the Redis server to find small bits of information. These are mostly read calls. 
My question is what is the maximum concurrent requests the Redis server can accept?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Maximum number of clients
In Redis 2.4 there was an hard-coded limit about the maximum number of clients that was possible to handle simultaneously.
In Redis 2.6 this limit is dynamic: by default is set to 10000 clients, unless otherwise stated by the maxmemory directive in Redis.conf.
However Redis checks with the kernel what is the maximum number of file descriptors that we are able to open (the soft limit is checked), if the limit is smaller than the maximum number of clients we want to handle, plus 32 (that is the number of file descriptors Redis reserves for internal uses), then the number of maximum clients is modified by Redis to match the amount of clients we are really able to handle under the current operating system limit.

You can check more on http://redis.io/topics/clients